# Is it possible to run parallel connection between Opencv Gstreamer?

Tags: multithreading, opencv, parallel-processing, gstreamer

I have 4 different stream. They are waiting for each other to establish a connection. Can I do a parallel operation. Only when I send the 9003 stream. I want to connect directly with 9003 without waiting for the others.

When I try with threads, the second thread does not start before the first thread ends.

My Code:

```
string gst_pipe1 = "udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";
string gst_pipe2 = "udpsrc port=9002 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";
string gst_pipe3 = "udpsrc port=9003 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";
string gst_pipe4 = "udpsrc port=9004 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";

thread get1([]() { videoCap[0] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe9001, CAP_GSTREAMER); }); 
thread get2([]() { videoCap[1] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe9002, CAP_GSTREAMER); }); 
thread get3([]() { videoCap[2] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe9003, CAP_GSTREAMER); }); 
thread get4([]() { videoCap[3] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe9004, CAP_GSTREAMER); }); 
get1.join(); 
get2.join(); 
get3.join(); 
get4.join();
```

---------------------------------**problem is solved.**---------------------------------

all the pipelines listen constantly. When a connection comes from anyone, it streams it.

In the future, I had to create a buffer for synchronization and I need to get all the frames when the connection comes.
, my solution c++ dll:

```
vector<cv::VideoCapture> videoCap(4);

string gst_pipe[] = {
"udpsrc port=9001 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false",
"udpsrc port=9002 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false",
"udpsrc port=9003 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false",
"udpsrc port=9004 caps = application/x-rtp ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false" };

void func1() {
    videoCap[0] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe[0], CAP_GSTREAMER);

    colorImages[0].create(Size(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight), CV_8UC3);


    while (true)
    {
        videoCap[0].read(colorImages[0]);
    }
}

void func2() {
    videoCap[1] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe[1], CAP_GSTREAMER);

    colorImages[1].create(Size(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight), CV_8UC3);


    while (true)
    {
        videoCap[1].read(colorImages[1]);
    }
}

void func3() {
    videoCap[2] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe[2], CAP_GSTREAMER);

    colorImages[2].create(Size(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight), CV_8UC3);


    while (true)
    {
        videoCap[2].read(colorImages[2]);
    }
}

void func4() {
    videoCap[3] = VideoCapture(gst_pipe[3], CAP_GSTREAMER);

    colorImages[3].create(Size(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight), CV_8UC3);


    while (true)
    {
        videoCap[3].read(colorImages[3]);
    }
}

void CaptureInitialize()
{
    std::thread td1(func1);
    std::thread td2(func2);
    std::thread td3(func3);
    std::thread td4(func4);
    td1.join();
    td2.join();
    td3.join();
    td4.join();
}


unsigned char* WrapperSingleCameras(int hCameraIndex)
{
    return colorImages[hCameraIndex].ptr();
}
```

GUI c#:

```
        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(DLLWrapper.CaptureInitialize);
            thread1.Start();
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(SplitBitmapInitialize);
            thread2.Start();
        }


unsafe private void SplitBitmapInitialize()
        {
            pt = new byte*[4];
            BitmapSingleImage = new Bitmap[4];

                while (true)
                {
                //DLLWrapper.mainThread();
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                    //DLLWrapper.WrapperGetFrame(i);
                    pt[i] = DLLWrapper.WrapperSingleCameras(i);

                        BitmapSingleImage[i] = new Bitmap(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight, 3 * rsSplitWidth, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)pt[i]);
                        //BitmapSingleImage[i] = new Bitmap(rsSplitWidth, rsSplitHeight, rsSplitWidth, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, (IntPtr)pt[i]);

                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                        videoCamTopLeft.Image = BitmapSingleImage[i];
                        videoCamTopLeft.Refresh();
                        }

                        else if (i == 1)
                        {
                        videoCamTopRight.Image = BitmapSingleImage[i];
                        videoCamTopRight.Refresh();
                    }
                        else if (i == 2)
                        {
                        videoCamBottomLeft.Image = BitmapSingleImage[i];
                        videoCamBottomLeft.Refresh();
                    }
                        else if (i == 3)
                        {
                        videoCamBottomRight.Image = BitmapSingleImage[i];
                        videoCamBottomRight.Refresh();
                    }
                }               
            }
```

Comment: I think the problem may be due to `nvh265dec` element. Afaik it is a hardware decoder, and you might be not able to instantiate more than once.

Comment: I solved the problem. I edited the question.